# Which applications of quantum singular value transformation use block-encodings in apriori unknown bases?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, grovers-algorithm, amplitude-amplification

Quantum singular value transformation (QSVT) algorithm allows performing polynomial transformations on matrices that are block-encoded in a unitary. Typically, block encoding is assumed to be 'the top-left' block encoding, meaning that

$$U=\begin{pmatrix} A & * \\ * & * \end{pmatrix} \ .$$

More generally, the block encoding only needs to take this form in some bases, i.e. in general
$$U=V\begin{pmatrix} A & * \\ * & * \end{pmatrix}W^\dagger$$
for some unitaries $V,W$. Importantly, QSVT does not require to to know $V,W$ explicitly, but only have access to the associated controlled projectors.

I believe that in most applications unitaries $V,W$ are simple, known and often $V=W=\mathbb{I}$, i.e. we have the top-left block encoding in the standard basis.

There is a case, however, where $V$ is not known explicitly - Grover's search. In this case, we know that the transition amplitude between $|0\rangle$ and some marked state $|m\rangle$ is block-encoded in $$H^{\otimes n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}}|m\rangle \langle 0|+\dots$$ but we don't know the exact basis transformation $V$ that makes this block-encoding top-left. However, just knowing that it exists and having access to Grover's oracle $C_{|m\rangle\langle m|}NOT$ allows to carry out QSVT and amplify the transition amplitude.

This case of the amplitude amplification algorithm strikes me as somewhat unusual, different from the other applications, such as Hamiltonian simulation, where the block encodings are explicit.

Am I right that the amplitude amplification is special in this regard? Are there other applications where we do not explicitly know $V,W$?